# When can vector fields span the tangent space at each point?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

If the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold is a smoothly trivial smooth fiber bundle, is it a trivial smooth vector bundle?
Since this question got no answer in MathExchange, I am migrating it here.

[Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4645955/333911)

Answer (score 4):

Take a vector bundle $V\to M$ which is trivial as a fiber bundle. Let $Z\subset V$ be the zero section, which is a smooth fiber bundle section, $Z(m)\in V_m$.
For each point $m\in M$, let $V'_m$ be the set of tangent vectors to $V$ at $Z(m)$ which lie tangent to the fiber of $V\to M$.
Then clearly $V$ is isomorphic to $V'$ as a vector bundle.
But $V'$ is invariant under any fiber bundle isomorphism preserving $Z$.
Trivialize $V$ as a fiber bundle by a map $V\xrightarrow{\varphi}M\times F$.
Consider the map
$$
\varphi'(Z(m))\colon V'_m\to T_{\varphi(Z(m))}F.
$$
This is a vector bundle isomorphism, so $V$ is isomorphic to the vector bundle
$$
V''_m:=T_{\varphi(Z(m))}F.
$$
But since $V$ is a vector bundle, the fibers are diffeomorphic to Euclidean space, i.e. we can assume that $F=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so we can identify all tangent spaces of $F$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$.